# TypeError: Cannot read property 'clickNode' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I created these two functions inside my react component. The following code returns an error:

```
const UncontrolledDiagram = ({ sentence }) => {
  // create diagrams schema

  const [schema, { onChange, addNode, removeNode }] = useSchema(initialSchema);

  const clickNode = () => {
    console.log("Click event");
  }
  const BaseNode = ({ content }) => (
    <div className='button' style={{ width: '70px', fontSize: '0.6rem', textAlign: 'center' }}>
      <a onClick={this.clickNode}>
        <div role="button">
          {content}
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
```

How can I call *clickNode* from within *BaseNode*?

Comment: try `<a onClick={() => clickNode()}>`

Comment: or even `<a onClick={clickNode}>` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You no need to write 'this' inside the functional components, so your code should looks like this

```
const UncontrolledDiagram = ({ sentence }) => {
  // create diagrams schema

  const [schema, { onChange, addNode, removeNode }] = useSchema(initialSchema);

  const clickNode = () => {
    console.log("Click event");
  }
  const BaseNode = ({ content }) => (
    <div className='button' style={{ width: '70px', fontSize: '0.6rem', textAlign: 'center' }}>
      <a onClick={clickNode}>
        <div role="button">
          {content}
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
```